# linux curlftpfs, password with '@'

Tags: passwords, sftp, curlftpfs

I want to mount an FTP drive, but my FTP password contains "@".

I enter the command:

```
curlftpfs myaccount:my@password@thefptserver.com mnt/my_ftp
```

But it gives me "Error connecting to ftp: Could not resolve host: password"

How do I fix this, no combination of wrapping things in '' work either they are completely ignored

Answer (score 5):

```
curlftpfs myaccount:my%40password@thefptserver.com:/ /mnt/my_ftp ...
```

where `%40` is hex for character @ .